# Average results from multiple simulations

Tags: netlogo

I have a simulation with a lot of random components, so I would like to run many simulations and average the results (the result is determined by a variable called score).

How would you do this in Netlogo?

Currently I'm working on a program that will export the results to csv, then I plan to use python/excel to average them. I don't like this because I want to run 100+ simulations (so there will be 100+ files)... I'm hoping there is a better solution

*EDIT* or an implementation of what I described (I have to relearn enough python/vba to solve this, so it's going to take me some time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple enough if you use [BehaviorSpace](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html).

In your experiment definition, put `score` in the **Measure runs using these reporters** textbox and uncheck **Measure run at every step**.

When you run your experiment, save your results using **Table output**. It will produce a `csv` that you can open in your spreadsheet application. From there, producing an average of the `score` column should be trivial.